# AAVERIFY in NSL

Tags: novell-idm, netiq

While using AAVERIFY wihtout any arguments like

AAVERIFY ?Result

I am not being prompted for a passwrd, it directly throws me the result as false.
Does anybody have any idea about this. It was working and suddenly now it skips the prompt of asking me the password.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a method for it to ask for anything.  That is sort of the point, to use something other than the password.  You use the -Method and the method name.  This needs NMAS on the client workstation or SLAA (Secure Login Advanced Auth agent) to actually do other things like smart cards, etc.